# List Form Validation Logic Not Working as Expected

Tags: 2010, list, validation

I'm trying to include Validation Settings for my List Form where I've got a column called `Food Service` and another column called `Food Service Type`, where `Food Service` is a "Yes/No" type column and `Food Service Type` is a "Choice Menu" where I've got one of the menu options as "Please Select an Option". I'm trying to validate to see if the user has "Yes" chosen for `Food Service`, that it should be checked if "Please Select an Option" is selected, and if it is, kick-back a message saying that they should select an option. My formula appears as follows:

```
=IF([Food Service]="Yes",IF([Food Service Type]="Please Select an Option", FALSE),TRUE)
```

I've tried a multitude of other different ways as a sort of sanity check, but unsuccessfully. I'm pretty sure the way it's working now, it sees that combination above as false, but then moves on to the Does anyone have suggestions on how to make this work (if not through list validation, another method)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is `Yes/No` then you should validate against `TRUE` and `FALSE`

So your formula will be

```
=IF(AND([Food Service]=TRUE,[Food Service Type]="Please Select an Option"),FALSE,TRUE)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. It still allows me to check "Yes" in `Food Service` while leaving the option "Please Select an Option" chosen in `Food Service Type` and create the event. I copied your code down as a sanity check and also tried using raw numbers and thinking maybe it was 0 based counting, starting with 0 and none of it worked.

Comment: Check your field names, and also try the updated formula

Answer (score 0):

I think your nested IF is missing the 3rd parameter that is causing the problem.
You should use one of the following

1. > =IF([Food Service]=**TRUE**,IF([Food Service Type]="Please Select an Option", FALSE, **TRUE**),TRUE)
2. Option suggested by Amal
3. Shorter version:

   > =NOT(AND([Food Service]=TRUE,[Food Service Type]="Please Select an Option"))

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! It's nice being able to see the various options and how the logic pans out in SharePoint.